# Was/were? Which one?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, existentials

There **was** a couple of months that were really stressful

There **were** a couple of months that were really stressful

Which one sounds better? Are they both acceptable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might think *there* is the subject of the sentence, but it's not -- this construct is a special case and here, the subject comes after the verb ([reference](http://www.learnamericanenglishonline.com/Blue%20Level/B16_Part_2_There_was.html)).

*Was* is the singular past tense of *be*, and *were* is the plural past tense form of *be*. Since *months* is actually the subject, you would use *were*.

Comment: That said, you will often hear native speakers of American English say "There was a couple of..." or "There was a few..." or something similar if they're speaking informally.

Comment: I wonder how you consider 'a couple' singular or plural.Oxforddictionaries. com consider it to be plural. Then using 'was' should be incorrect, shouldn't it?

Comment: @stangdon it is indeed an AE native speaker. The comment helped a lot, thanks.